# Getting the average of the same dict keys in a list of nested dicts

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have 1000 of lists of nested dicts like this. This is an example of one list of nested dicts, the other ones have same keys:

```
[{'key1': {'key1': array([[1.]]),
   'key2': array([[1.]]),
   'key3': array([[1.]]),
   'key4': array([[0.85722112]])}},
 {'key2': {'key1': array([[1.]]),
   'key2': array([[1.]]),
   'key3': array([[1.]]),
   'key4': array([[0.85722112]])}},
 {'key3': {'key1': array([[1.]]),
   'key2': array([[1.]]),
   'key3': array([[1.]]),
   'key4': array([[0.85722112]])}},
 {'key4': {'key1': array([[0.85722112]]),
   'key2': array([[0.85722112]]),
   'key3': array([[0.85722112]]),
   'key4': array([[1.]])}}]
```

I have spent some time researching and still haven't found if there is a way I could calculate averages across all the lists of nested dicts based on the same key without brute-forcing. Is there some command in json library for this?

Comment: Could you show us your expected output and your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do that:

```
t = pd.json_normalize([list(x.values())[0] for x in l])
```

At this point, the value of t is:

```
             key1            key2            key3            key4
0         [[1.0]]         [[1.0]]         [[1.0]]  [[0.85722112]]
1         [[1.0]]         [[1.0]]         [[1.0]]  [[0.85722112]]
2         [[1.0]]         [[1.0]]         [[1.0]]  [[0.85722112]]
3  [[0.85722112]]  [[0.85722112]]  [[0.85722112]]         [[1.0]]
```

Now, do:

```
t = t.applymap(lambda x: x[0][0])
t.mean()
```

The output is:

```
key1    0.964305
key2    0.964305
key3    0.964305
key4    0.892916
dtype: float64
```